# What replace method can I use to replace a substring from a String?

Tags: java, replace, stack-overflow

How can I replace it?
I've been trying this:

```
string.replaceFirst(substring, "");
```

but it's not replacing, and as I am doing a recursive method, it's giving me a StackOverflowException..

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String are immutable, which means you cannot change them once they are initialized.

The `replaceFirst` method creates a new string where the first instance is replaced by your replacement and returns it...the original string is never modified.

You're code should be something like this

```
string = string.replaceFirst(substring,"")
```

Comment: @st0le: an answer can at earliest only be accepted 15 minutes after the question is been posted.

Comment: @BalusC, hehe, but its no parrot... :P

Comment: If you didn't notice, yesterday toinght I've updated my Gravatar as well.

Comment: @BalusC, I did , but between the both of us you're 1 cap and a Chichiray ahead of me.... :P

Comment: @BalusC-Would you mind taking a look at this ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532009/placing-error-message-for-a-checkbox-array

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other replys that Strings are immutable, note that replaceFirst takes in a Regular Expression not a substring. (The two might be the same in some cases but not all).   Either way this more than likely is unrelated to your StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 2):

This method not modifying current String. It returns new string with replacement.
String newString = string.replaceFirst(substring, "");

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

> string = string.replaceAll(substring, replacement_string).